# Extracting text tags in order - How can this be done?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to find all the text along with the parent tag in the HTML. In the example below, the variable named `html` has the sample HTML where I try to extract the tags and the text.
This works fine and as expected gives out the `tags` with the `text`

Here I have used `cheerio` to traverse DOM. `cheerio`  works exactly same as `jquery`.

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const html = `
                    <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                <p>
                  Regular bail is the legal procedure through which a court can direct 
                  release of persons in custody under suspicion of having committed an offence, 
                  usually on some conditions which are designed to ensure 
                  that the person does not flee or otherwise obstruct the course of justice. 
                  These conditions may require executing a “personal bond”, whereby a person
                  pledges a certain amount of money or property which may be forfeited if 
                  there is a breach of the bail conditions. Or, a court may require
                  executing a bond “with sureties”, where a person is not seen as 
                  reliable enough and may have to present 
                  <em>other persons</em> to vouch for her, 
                  and the sureties must execute bonds pledging money / property which 
                  may be forfeited if the accused person breaches a bail condition.
                </p>
                </body>
            </html>

`;

const getNodeType = function (renderedHTML, el, nodeType) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(renderedHTML)

    return $(el).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == nodeType;
    });
}

let allTextPairs = [];
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
getNodeType(html, $("html"), 3).map((i, node) => {
            const parent = node.parentNode.tagName;
            const nodeValue = node.nodeValue.trim();
            allTextPairs.push([parent, nodeValue])
});

console.log(allTextPairs);
```

as shown below

[image]

But the problem is that the text tags extracted are out of order. If you see the above screenshot, `other persons` has been reported in the end, although it should occur before `to vouch for her ...`. Why does this happen? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just walk the tree in depth order. Walk function courtesy of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/apaleslimghost/c4f67949eb47ea532dc27a6d8d93d274).

```
function walk(el, fn, parents = []) {
  fn(el, parents);
  (el.children || []).forEach((child) => walk(child, fn, parents.concat(el)));
}
walk(cheerio.load(html).root()[0], (node, parents) => {
  if (node.type === "text" && node.data.trim()) {
    console.log(parents[parents.length - 1].name, node.data);
  }
});
```

This prints out the stuff, but you could just as well put it in that array of yours.

Comment: Umm, I did not understand. How is this exactly different from `getNodeType`? Could you please explain to me in this context?

Comment: The recursive walk function ensures it's walking through the DOM tree in document order. I think the combination of `.addBack()`, etc. messes up the Cheerio traversal.

Comment: Any suggestion on improving the same function so that it preserves the order?

Comment: Honestly, no. :)

Comment: Why is `node.type` a `string` here? (i.e. "text") Isn't it normally a number? Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: `nodeType` isn't the same as Cheerio's `node.type`.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to accommodate `find(":not(iframe)")` in your answer? It has been there in my earlier approach.

Comment: Does it matter? But yeah, you could see if there are any `iframe`s in the parents and ignore them.

Comment: In the callback function of `walk`, how can I get the class names for `node`? Earlier I was doing, `$(node.parent).hasClass("some-class")` but this not longer works